# Initiating a random amount of instances of a class with different names?

Tags: c#, .net

How would I go about Initiating random amount of instances of a class with different names?

The example scenario I have was for a rogue-like-text-adventure game. You walk into a room and a random number of enemies generate, the enemies are instances of an enemy class.

They all have different instance names so that when you attack one of them then only that one enemy loses health.

I've gotten as far as making a random generator, putting it into a for loop and then calling a new class instance called "classInstance1" but it of course overwrites it, so if I were to reduce the value of "classInstance1.hp" then that would reduce the health of all the enemies in the room.

I need a way to know how to generate multiple instances with different instance names ("`classInstance2`", "`classInstance3`" etc.) so I can then use/manipulate all the individual instances.

Is there a specific way of going about this?

Comment: There would be ways to generate a different name for each class instance, but your real issue is, that you work on names when you should work on class objects. When a specific enemy instance is in battle with the player, you should handle all activity by referencing this instance, not by passing some name around.

Comment: Solved: https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus

Comment: @grek40 thanks man, helps me learn a lot actually. I've been working with names for all my time learning C# (bar arrays) but I need to certainly look into Lists and Collections a lot more to get my headspace aligned with the correct way of tackling it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)!

It's like an array, but you can dynamically change the size of it.

Let's create a `List<Enemy>`:

```
private List<Enemy> enemies = new List<Enemy>();
```

To randomly generate a number of enemies, you can do this:

```
int count = YourRandomGenerator.NextInt(10);
for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
    enemies.Add(new Enemy());
}
```

To access a particular enemy, use `[]`:

```
enemies[0] // first enemy
enemies[1] // second enemy
// etc
```

Comment: Thanks man! Perfect explanation! Ill do some reading on Lists. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Need to push every object (Enemy) into a List:**

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
 int randomEnemies= rnd.Next(1, 10); //random number of enemies

List<Enemy> enemyList = new List<Enemy>();

for (int i = 0; i < randomEnemies; i++)
{
   Enemy enemy= new Enemy() { name= "bad people",damage= "15"}
   enemyList .Add(enemy);
}
```

**Access the object enemy one by one:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
      Enemy enemy = enemyList[i];
}
```

**Enemy class:**

```
 public class Enemy 
    {
        public string name{ get; set; }

        public string damage{ get; set; }
    }
```

More about List you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Naming conventions for public [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzcth91k(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This really helps me out, Ill do a little bit more reading on Lists before diving into it :D